# Good example Go code with standard library usage

Tags: go, standard-library

One of the rather daunting things for me in picking up a new language is the standard library: is it large? What does it have in it? How often is it used? What conventions does it use?

I've been reading the Go tutorial and Effective Go, but I'd like to look at some idiomatic example code for complete (but not too complex) programs, and see how they make use of Go's standard library.

If you have a sample project sitting around you'd be willing to share, or you know of one that would be good to study, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to take a look into the - still growing - packages of my Tideland Common Go Library at http://code.google.com/p/tideland-cgl/source/browse/. So if you find something unclear there you can ask me.

Comment: Thanks. Where would you recommend I start reading, as a beginner?

Comment: Hehe, for German speaking people it's no problem: I would recommend my book "Systemprogrammierung in Google Go". http://amzn.to/emX68O. But otherwise you should start with the Go site, here the tutorial and "Effective Go" as well as the specification. Additionally there's much more documentation on this side. And you should subscribe to the mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts.

Comment: New link is broken :P

Comment: Ouch, thanks for the hint. Yes, I followed the masses and moved all my sources to GitHub. So now they can be found at https://github.com/tideland. There are several projects containing lots of packages.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/) and [source code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/) for the standard Go packages.

Answer (score 0):

`_test.go` files in each package show actual code using that package. For example, [this](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/archive/tar/writer_test.go) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/archive/tar/reader_test.go) show how to use `archive/tar` package.